# How to complete 5,000,000 lifetime meters in level 11?

Tags: achievements, temple-run-2

[image]

How to complete 5,000,000 lifetime meters in level 11?

Comment: Just keep running?

Comment: I agree with @TimmyJim

Answer (score 1):

As [@TimmyJim said](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/313069/how-to-complete-5-000-000-lifetime-meters-in-level-11#comment445460_313069), just keep running.

[According to Cole Stobbs](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-average-speed-of-the-runner-in-Temple-run), the average running speed in Temple Run 2 is 12.5 m/s.

Dividing 5,000,000 meters by 12.5 gives us a total of 400,000 seconds. [According to Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=400000%20seconds), **this converts to 4 days, 15 hours, 6 minutes, and 40 seconds of total playtime to unlock the achievement.**

Comment: This tells how long, but doesn't tell *how* to achieve it. Wouldn't a better answer give some sort of general strategies?

Comment: It's a cumulative achievement. The only real strategy is to keep playing

Comment: yes, but getting further in each game would decrease the overall time spent towards the achievement (restart-related times, overall frustration and necessary breaks taken).